# Setting header in citrus http request

Tags: citrus-framework

Is it possible to set the "Accept-Charset" header in a citrus http request? I have tried : 
`http().client(endpoint).send().get().payload().header("Accept-Charset", "utf-8")`

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrus uses the Spring RestTemplate for sending Http client requests. The RestTemplate by default uses the `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter` which by default has the option  `writeAcceptCharset=true`.

This option causes the converter to automatically add all available charsets in the `Accept-Charset` header. So you will end up with a request that has all available charsets of your environment as complete list set in the Http headers.

In case you want to disable this option you need to set a custom RestTemplate on the Citrus http-client component with a StringHttpMessageConverter that has `writeAcceptCharset` option set to 'false'.